# Sorting Minutes

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, laravel-5, collections

im trying to sort soccer minutes, but is not sorting right, for example in soccer is very normal minutes be like "1,2,3,40+5...". Basically is saying 40 minutes + 5 minutes (45 minutes).
So in my records i a colllection like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 9876,
    "minute": "90+30",
  },
  {
    "id": 9874,
    "minute": "90+10",
  },
  {
    "id": 9873,
    "minute": "105",
  },
  {
    "id": 9873,
    "minute": "90",
  },
 ...
]
```

So to make it order the minutes right, i need to use explode on the string "minute", than make a array_sum, but in my code, it still doesnt order right, still in the 105 is above of "90+10".

Here is my code:

```
$timelines = SoccerTime::where('match_id',$id)
        ->orderBy('minute', 'desc')
        ->get();
$collection = collect($timelines);
$sorted = $collection->sortByDesc('minute');
$test = $sorted->values()->all();

//Here i begin the new Sort
$newSort =  collect($test)->sort(function ($a, $b) {
    return array_sum(explode("+",$a->minute)) -  array_sum(explode("+",$b->minute));
});
return  $newSort;
```

Comment: why use "90+10" over "100" ? Even if you want to use "90+10" you could store both, one for display and one for sorting

Comment: hoo you give me a idea, ill create a property where i sum it, and then sort by this one, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change a couple of field in your model. I'd use a `minute` field to store the actual minute (`100` in cases like your "90+10" example) and another integer field `period` to indicate the "period", where:

- `1` for 1T
- `2` for 2T
- `3` for 1ET
- `4` for 2ET
.

So your new way of sorting should be:
First by `period` (solving your problem of getting 90'+4' of 2T before 93' of 1ET) and then by `minute` (the actual sort).

It would be so much easier and it could also help you to do some other reporting queries.